# How do I get the value from a callback - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

```
    function myCallback(myData){  
            //data is here myData  

    }


    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data;
        rbf_selectQuery("SELECT name, base, per, one_time_setup, annual FROM service_fees", 10000, myCallback);
       //I want to get the data to here
       console.log(data);
   });
```

I am querying data using a clientside call from a proprietary software platform that supports jQuery and Javascript. The function returns the data in a callback. How can I get the data back into the main scope? Globals? return the value from the function?

Comment: Use closure instead of top-level function as callback.

Comment: @VallyN please elaborate with an example

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?rq=1